# Missing required parameters for Route (Laravel 8)

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I get this error when I create or edit a form, do you know if it comes from one of these views or from the Controller?

> Missing required parameter for [Route: forms.show] [URI: forms/{form}] [Missing parameter: form]

Thankstrong texts for your help, this is my first post here.

Code below :

CONTROLLER
FormsController:

```
public function create()
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('login');
        }
        return view('forms.create');
    }

public function show($id)
    {
        return view('forms.consult', ['forms' => Forms::findOrFail($id)]);
    }

public function update(StoreFormsRequest $request, Forms $forms)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('login');
        }
        $request->validated();
        $forms->update($request->input());
        return redirect()->route('forms.show', ['forms' => $forms]);
    }

public function edit($id)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('login');
        }
        return view('forms.edit', ['forms' => Forms::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
```

VIEW
create.blade.php:

```
<form action="{{ url('forms') }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
...
<button class="btn btn-primary mb-1 mr-1" type="submit"> Ajouter </button>
</form>
```

edit.blade.php :

```
<form action="{{ url('forms', [$forms->id]) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')
...
<button class="btn btn-primary mb-1 mr-1" type="submit"> Modifier </button>
</form>
```

ROUTE

```
web.php :
Route::get('/', [FormsController::class, 'index']);
Route::resource('forms', FormsController::class);

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\FormsController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Comment: Normally it's a problem in your view, but without the code calling your route we cannot do a lot of things. Please be sure you're calling the route with `route('forms.show', ['form' => {yourform}])`

Comment: Hard to tell without any code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's ok, I updated the post :)

Comment: For one, having two routes pointing to `/home` with the same name will not do what you think it does. How is code supposed to know which Controller to use? Resource controllers/routes take the singular of the route as parameter: [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your controller passes a parameter called `forms`  instead of `form`. But your route is expecting a `form` parameter.

Change this:

```
return redirect()->route('forms.show', ['forms' => $forms]);
```

to this:

```
return redirect()->route('forms.show', ['form' => $forms]);
```

Comment: despite the modification of the route the problem persists .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are passing 'form' parameter to the route. Use [helper methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers)
in view for example as

```
{{ route('forms.show', ['form' => 1]) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Route::resource will create the route parameters for your resource routes based on the "singularized" version of the resource name.

you need to pass the singular name of the resource ie singular name of the controller   FormsController should be pass as **form** instead of **forms**.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters

I faced the same issue in my project , i passed singular name of controller and it worked.